# Combination of betting odds in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, combinations

So I'm new to Python and I've decided to work on a project that I'm interested in. I've connected to an API to get betting odds from different bookies. I've successfully got the data and stored in a Sqlite3 database. The next step is to compare the odds, and this is where I'm getting stuck.

So let's say I have a list of odds from 3 bookies:

bookie1 = [1,2]

bookie2 = [3,4]

bookie3 = [5,6]

then I have the odds from all bookies in 1 list, such as:

bookies_all = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]

How do I get the combinations of odds from the 3 bookies?

I expect the output to look something like this:

combos = [[1,3], [1,5], [1,4], [1,6], [2,3], [2,5], [2,4], [2,6], [3,5], [3,6],[4,5], [4,6]]

Is the best option to loop through the list?

Answer (score 0):

I've coded this up and it gives me all the combinations I need.

```
bookies_all = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
combos = []

count = 0
for outer in bookies_all:
    for inner in bookies_all:
        temp_list = [outer[0], inner[1]]
        count += 1
        combos.append(temp_list)

print(combos)
```

Output: [[1, 2], **[1, 4]**, **[1, 6]**, **[3, 2]**, [3, 4], **[3, 6]**, **[5, 2]**, **[5, 4]**, [5, 6]]

The combinations in bold are the ones I want. This code works for this example.

I will test it out for scenarios where the `bookies_all` list has more values.

Comment: Welcome to the site! In future it would be best practice to have a go before posting your question, and then post your code so far in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to find the combinations of bookies, then use a list comprehension to interleave the items:

```
from itertools import combinations

bookies_all = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

all_comb = list(combinations(bookies_all, 2))
#print(all_comb)

combos = [[i, j] for c in all_comb for i in c[0] for j in c[1]]
print(combos)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5], [4, 6]]
```